# What is this behaviour called? Am I initializing the class A here?

Tags: c++

What does it mean by `A A` in function `g`? What is the behavior called? Am I initializing the `class A`? Could somebody explain this? Thanks for your valuable time!

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class A {
        public:
    };

    void g()
    {
        A A; 

//if I declare 'A A;' and 'A a1' together here, then I could get an error "[Error] expected ';' before 'a1' " 
    }

    main(){
        A a2;
    }
```

Comment: what if you try `A a1;` instead of `A a1`?

Comment: @sree `A a1` doesn't error out there.

Comment: http://liveworkspace.org/code/2eAaPr$0 Declaring `A a1` compiles smoothly.

Comment: Which compiler ? I have no problem w/ gcc 4.5.3

Comment: no not for me!! I am using dev C++ compiler, it gives an error "expected ';' before 'a1'" !!

Comment: Looks like the second A shadows the first A. From that point on to the end of scope, A is a variable and the class can be accessed as ::A only.

Comment: You should clarify you put `A a1` after `A A`, not instead of.

Comment: this compiles with VS2010, whether I use `A A;` or `A a1`, as as @n.m says, the `A A` creates a local instance of class A, which shadows class A. Frankly, I'm surprised it compiles, but it appears to compile and run (at least in VS2010)

Comment: to put `A a1` after `A A` you would have to use: `::A a1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are declaring a variable of type `A`, whose name is also `A`.

After that declaration, until the end of the scope, the unqualified name `A` refers to the variable, not the type; so a declaration `A a1;` is not valid. Since the type is in the global namespace, you can refer to that as `::A`, even after the declaration of the variable `A`.

Comment: RE: "You are declaring a variable of type `A`, whose name is also `A`. **Question:** Are there situations where this could be of real use? Or, in general, is this considered a bad practice?

Comment: @DavidRR: I can't think of any reason why you'd specifically want to do that; and it's probably better to avoid doing it in order to reduce the scope for confusion. Personally, I use different capitalisation conventions for types and variables, so the situation never arises.

Comment: I agree. And I can't think of reasons for doing this in any other language, either. So, I don't think this advice is unique to C++.

Comment: thank you guys for your explanation!@Mike Seymour special thank's for your answer.